# Why does the "No Target rule error" keeps on occurring even after providing target rule in Android.mk file?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, skia

Iam trying to configure CPP files from SKIA library in NDK project.
The error ***make: ***No rule to make target*** keeps on occurring even after i have provided target rule in Android.mk file. Here is my code

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
CC=gcc
CC_FLAGS=-I

include $(CLEAR_VARS) # clear out the variables of the previous module

# Name of the module that the app will reference with System.loadLibrary
LOCAL_MODULE := hello_skia_ndk

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CC_FLAGS)

# List   source files compiled for this module

PROJECT_FILES:= $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
PROJECT_FILES+= helloskia.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(PROJECT_FILES)

# jnigraphics defines the function AndroidBitmap_lockPixels, which we need in order to draw into
# android.graphics.Bitmap

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ljnigraphics -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.